# Calculator program with C

Tags: c, calculator

I have a program for a basic calculator. It is supposed to add/subtract/multiply/divide.
I can get it to perform one operation, but not consecutive ones. Any help?

I'm not really sure what function to use. I want it to do something repeatedly I should use a loop, right? but how?

Here is the code. thanks for the input!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )

{ char op; double result = 0.0, num;

    printf("The calculator is on.\nPerform an operation:0.0");
    scanf("%c", &op);

    while(op != result)
    {     

        scanf("%lf", &num);

        if( op=='+')
        {result+=num;
            printf("The new result is %6.2f", result);
        }
        else if(op=='-')
        {result-=num; 
            printf("The new result is %6.2f", result);
        }
        else if(op=='*')
        {result*=num;
            printf("The new result is %6.2f", result);
        }
        else if(op=='/')
        {result/=num;
            printf("The new result is %6.2f", result);
        }
        else{
            printf("Not an operation of the function.\nTry again.");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A some point, you may want `scanf(" %c", &op);`  (Add space). And put that `scanf()` also inside the loop.

Comment: Your return 0 is inside the loop so you will exit there. But What are you trying to do? You read one operation and plenty of times a number? And if the operation is unknown you ask to enter a number again but offer no way to change the operation.

Comment: This look like a homework...

Comment: Cmoi: I made you edit and now i can do all the operations repeatedly. but now whenever i multiply or divide it does it infinitely

Answer (score 1):

```
while(op != result)
```

Is almost certainly wrong. This will terminate the loop whenever the result matches the ascii value of the operation. So if the result is 42 when multiplying, 43 when adding, 45 when subtracting, or 47 when dividing.

I think you should either pick a code for "quit", maybe 'q', and check for that in the loop.

```
while(op != 'q')
```

Or, check that the file has not reached EOF, otherwise quit. This is the usual strategy for shell programs of this sort.